# How do I confiugre nginx to send a specific static file when a specific url is requested?

Tags: nginx

I have a file, say `client.app.js`, which I want to send when `http://mydomain.local/app.js` is requested.

I want to only send a single specific file when get a specific request.

How do I configure nginx to work like this?

Answer (score 2):

To change the URI you can use a `rewrite` directive. The simplest solution is a rewrite statement at the server block level, or within the location block that processes the original request (assuming that `/client.app.js` is a valid URI) (see [this document](http://nginx.org/en/docs/http/ngx_http_rewrite_module.html#rewrite) for details):

```
rewrite ^/app.js$ /client.app.js last;
```

Alternatively, use an exact match location. This also gives you the ability to set the `root` of the replacement file (see [this document](http://nginx.org/en/docs/http/ngx_http_core_module.html#location) for details):

```
location = /app.js {
    root /path/to/file/dir;
    rewrite ^ /client.app.js break;
}
```